# Playing a The First Video located in a random folder/subfolder

Tags: batch-file

I would like to make a `.bat` file that will open the first file within a random folder/subfolders, in the same location as the `.bat` file.

The code I currently have only opens a random file.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "rootFolder=G:\Movies\Anime" 

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in (`
    cmd /q /v /e /c "for /f delims^= %%a in ('dir /a-d /s /b "%rootFolder%"') do echo(!random!:%%a"
    ^| sort 2^>nul
    ^| cmd /q /e /v /c "set /p ".^=" & echo(!.!"
`) do start "" "%%~b"
```

I also have a `.bat` file that generates a text file with a list of all folders in the same location. I'm not sure if it would be easier to reference that.

```
dir /b > Animelist.txt
```

Also if possible how to exclude it opening particular types of files such as jpegs / the other `.bat` file?

Comment: Instead of `dir /a-d /s /b "%rootFolder%"`, write `dir /a-d /s /b "%rootFolder%\*.avi" "%rootFolder%\*.mpg" "%rootFolder%\*.wmv" "%rootFolder%\*.mp4" "%rootFolder%\*.m4v" "%rootFolder%\*.mkv" ...` to handle files with certain extensions only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "rootFolder=%cd%"
    set fileTypes= "*.avi" "*.mpeg" "*.mkv" 

    pushd "%rootFolder%" && (
        for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=:" %%a in (`
            cmd /q /v /e /c "set p=&for /r %%a in (%fileTypes%) do if not !f!==%%~dpa (set f=%%~dpa&set /a ((%random% %% 16273^)+1^)*!random!&echo :%%~dpa)"
            ^| sort 2^>nul
            ^| cmd /q /e /v /c "set /p ".^=" && echo(!.!"
        `) do pushd "%%~b." && (
            for /f "delims=" %%c in ('
                dir /b /a-d /on %fileTypes% 2^>nul 
                ^| cmd /q /e /v /c "set /p ".^=" && echo(!.!"
            ') do start "" "%%~fc"
            popd
        )
        popd
    )
```

Decomposing the task in pieces

- Configure where to search and what to search (first two `set`)
- Change to the starting folder (`pushd`)

  - Execute a recursive search for the indicated file types and output the name of the folder where the file has been found (first `cmd` inside `for /f`

    - As more than one file can be found in the same folder, check that we will not output a duplicate element (`if` inside first `cmd`)
  - For each folder, generate a random number as a prefix (`set /a`) and output the folder (`echo`)
  - Sort the list on the random number (`sort`)
  - Get the first folder in the list. As the list is sorted on a random number, this folder has been random selected (second `cmd` inside `for /f %%a`)
  - Discard the random number and retrieve only the folder (the reason for the `delims` and `tokens` in the `for /f %%a`)
- Change to the selected folder (`pushd`)

  - List the files of the indicated types inside the selected folder (`dir`)
  - From this list select only the first file (`cmd`)
  - Retrieve the selected file (`for /f %%c`)
  - Start the selected file (`start`)
  - Return to previous folder (`popd`)
- Return to the starting folder (`popd`)

Comment: Hey just tried this one works great just added in a few more variants of file formats, did run into a problem that didn't occur to me. after a few runs of the .bat I noticed it picks random subfolders too.

so from my example it'll play the first video from anything from season 1 to season 5, Would be more appropriate to pick from the first sub folder only.

Comment: @Josh, as stated *"... first file within a random folder/subfolders, ..."*. You need to include in your questions more, or at least more precise, information on what the problem is. Without it we are just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

The random selection of a folder is unambiguous.
The `first video file` is a bit more difficult. If using dir with several extensions like @aschipfl suggested, this  predetermines which extensions are looked for and found first.
The other way with excluding file types is more tedious without knowing which types might occur.

Here my batch **Edited** Streamlined some parts:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions Enabledelayedexpansion
Set Cnt=0
Set "Exclude=.bat$ .cmd$ .jpg$ .jpeg$ .txt$"

Pushd "G:\Movies\Anime" 
(Echo::: Numbered List of folders
  For /f "delims=" %%F in (
    'Dir /B/S/AD/ON'
  ) Do Set /A Cnt+=1&Echo:!Cnt!:%%F 
)>DirList.txt

:: Get Random num 1..Cnt
Set /A RndDir=%Random% %% Cnt+1

:: Get random folder name
For /f "tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%F in (
  'Findstr "^%RndDir%:" DirList.txt '
) Do Set "DirName=%%G"
Echo selected %RndDir% of %Cnt% = folder %DirName%
Pushd "%DirName%

Set "FileName"
For /f "Delims=" %%F in (
  'Dir /B/A-D ^|findstr /i /V "%Exclude%"'
) Do If Not defined FileName Set "FileName=%%~F"
If defined FileName Start "" "%FileName%"
Popd
Popd
Goto :Eof
```

Comment: The file formats are unison within each folder so this still works out okay overall for me, But I can see this as a problem for others only thing I could think of as a solution is to get the names of the files and search for numbers and order them respectively in a list and pick the first file from that.